# Header&Implementation files Visual Studio 2017 C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Why in Visual Studio 2017 the compiler will complain (LinkError 2019, seems to not compile the implementation) if I include my headers and implementation files rather than use the default pch.h and pch.cpp files? Obviously all the files mentioned are in the same folder.

(Note: Copy-Paste the same code in pch.h and pch.cpp will work fine)

Im using this sintax on header.h:

```
#pragma once
//init code
```

Implementation.cpp:

```
#include "header.h"
//impl code
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include "header.h"
//main code
```

Comment: You should learn about [precompiled headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/creating-precompiled-header-files?view=vs-2017)

Comment: 1) There is no requirement, that you must use precompiled headers. You can disable them for your project. 2) "_the compiler will complain_" Is not a descriptive problem description. Will complain _how_?

Comment: Did you actually include the files in the project or did you just put them in the folder on the file system?

Comment: 1) The compiler will complain throwing me LNK2019 error, and writing wrong sintax on the implementation file will not throw anything about that (the LNK error will remain but thats all) so i guessed that the compiler doesnt compile the implementation file.
2) Yes, obviously i included all the needed files with #include statement as you can read above

Comment: Pay attention to the compile *warnings*.  The compiler does not yell loudly enough when it can't find the precompiled header file.  Just a warning, it skips everything else in the .cpp file while searching for the #include.  Since a warning doesn't prevent linking, you'll easily get LNK2019 next.  And that's a loud one, preventing your eyes from seeing the more relevant warning.  Changing the name of the pch file requires changing the setting for the name on all the source files in the project.

Comment: I didnt change the pch.h and the pch.cpp file, they're stiil here, and thats not my intention. I thought that i could include the header.h and implementation.cpp in main.cpp simply including header.h in main. But now i guess i have to include header.h in pch.h and let it compile from there. Am i right?